# how do I quit a web driver session after the code has finished executing?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid2

We're using Selenium's Python bindings at work. Occasionally I forget to put the call to WebDriver.quit() in a finally clause, or the tear down for a test. Something bad happens, an exception is thrown, and the session is abandoned and stuck as "in use" on the grid.

How can I quit those sessions and return them to being available for use without restarting the grid server?

Comment: Why not inherit from a base test fixture that always calls `.quit` in it's `teardown`? You don't ever have to worry about it then.

Comment: @Arran [tearDown in unittest should be executed regardless of result in setUp](http://bugs.python.org/issue5538) is expected once you've had to deal with it, or read/remember [TestCase.tearDown()'s description](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) very carefully.


That is somewhat of an aside, though, as Selenium isn't always used in a test. We use it for task automation, and it isn't uncommon for me to use it in an interactive Python session and completely forget to clean up after myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While quitting in an ensure/finally block would be the safest option, configuring the idle timeout for your browser session would be a good safety release.  See the section on timeouts in the Grid 2 wiki page:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the node instead of the server.